# entity-find with select-field gives error msg

Tags: moqui

when run the following code :

```
 <entity-find entity-name="mantle.order.OrderHeaderPartFacilityStatus" list="orderPartList">
                <econdition field-name="facilityId" from = "facilityId"/>
                <econdition field-name="statusId" operator="in" value="OrderPlaced,"/>

                <!-- <select-field field-name="orderId, "/> -->
                <!-- <select-field field-name="orderName"/> -->
                <!-- <select-field field-name="placedDate"/> -->
                <!-- <select-field field-name="grandTotal"/> -->
                <!-- <select-field field-name="orderPartSeqId"/> -->
                <!-- <select-field field-name="facilityId"/> -->
                <!-- <select-field field-name="facilityName"/> -->
                <!-- <select-field field-name="partStatusId"/> -->
                <!-- <order-by field-name="orderPartSeqId"/> -->
        </entity-find>
```

I got:

```
 "orderPartList": [
    {
        "enteredByPartyId": null,
        "salesChannelEnumId": null,
        "recurrenceInfoId": null,
        "customerRoleTypeId": "Manager",
        "billingAccountId": null,
        "placedDate": "2016-01-01T00:00:00+0000",
        "telecomContactMechId": null,
        "postalContactMechId": null,
        "vendorRoleTypeId": null,
        "visitId": null,
        "lastOrderedDate": null,
        "remainingSubTotal": null,
        "trackingNumber": null,
        "otherPartyOrderId": null,
        "statusId": "OrderPlaced",
        "giftMessage": null,
        "entryDate": null,
        "shippingInstructions": null,
        "autoCancelDate": null,
        "estimatedDeliveryDate": null,
        "customerPartyId": "EX_JOHN_DOE",
        "validThruDate": null,
        "carrierPartyId": null,
        "partTotal": 5.1E+2,
        "facilityId": "FWorkshopnanneihuan",
        "syncStatusId": null,
        "estimatedShipDate": null,
        "validFromDate": null,
        "estimatedPickUpDate": null,
        "externalRevision": null,
        "orderPartSeqId": "01",
        "terminalId": null,
        "shipmentMethodEnumId": null,
        "shipBeforeDate": null,
        "parentOrderId": null,
        "isGift": null,
        "productStoreId": null,
        "orderRevision": 26,
        "dontCancelSetDate": null,
        "pseudoId": "FWorkshopnanneihuan",
        "dontCancelSetUserId": null,
        "systemMessageRemoteId": null,
        "maySplit": null,
        "externalId": null,
        "parentPartSeqId": null,
        "facilityName": "\u5357\u5185\u73af\u8f66\u95f4",
        "orderId": "FOJohndoePassat",
        "vendorPartyId": null,
        "shipAfterDate": null,
        "currencyUomId": null,
        "orderName": "John_doe order 1",
        "grandTotal": 5.1E+2,
        "partStatusId": "OrderOpen",
        "partName": "\u7b2c\u4e00\u90e8\u5206 John doe",
        "statusDescription": "Placed"
    }
],
```

But when I uncommented the select-field tag, as the following:

```
 <entity-find entity-name="mantle.order.OrderHeaderPartFacilityStatus" list="orderPartList">
                <econdition field-name="facilityId" from = "facilityId"/>
                <econdition field-name="statusId" operator="in" value="OrderPlaced,"/>

                <select-field field-name="orderId, "/>
                <!-- <select-field field-name="orderName"/> -->
                <!-- <select-field field-name="placedDate"/> -->
                <!-- <select-field field-name="grandTotal"/> -->
                <!-- <select-field field-name="orderPartSeqId"/> -->
                <!-- <select-field field-name="facilityId"/> -->
                <!-- <select-field field-name="facilityName"/> -->
                <!-- <select-field field-name="partStatusId"/> -->
                <!-- <order-by field-name="orderPartSeqId"/> -->
        </entity-find>
```

I then got the following error msg, which might suggest that the select sql not working:

```
{"errorCode":500,"errors":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Maps with null keys can't be converted to JSON"}
```

Something wrong?
I am runing MoquiDemo-2.0.0 with customized data. 
It might be a bug or something?  Someone has clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field-name "orderId, " is not valid. The comma is used to separate multiple field names so it turns that into a list of "orderId" and "", and an empty string is not a valid field name.

Similarly in your econdition on statusId the @value attribute has a comma at the end. If you are trying to include records with a null statusId use the econdition.@or-null attribute. For a more efficient query if that isn't what you are looking for, get rid of the comma and use the equals operator (which is the default so you don't need the operator attribute).

In general this code is sloppy. Moqui tries to be tolerant of funny things and do its best, but invalid field names and such are still invalid and you'll get errors. You may have more errors or warnings in the server side log as well, that is usually the first place to look if something isn't working right.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I use comma just for a reminder that I will add more values to the value tuple. I thought Moqui will get rid of the blank element in the tuple. Not getting rid of blanks is considerable , as sometimes people will need blank as a valid value. As you said, I get rid of the commas, the return value is getting all the other fields with the null value set except the field selected. Should it only fetch the value of the fields being selected and expose only the fields being selected?